# How to disable navigation animation and remove the screen title when using ReactNative's StackNavigator?

Tags: react-native

I've created a ReactNative app that uses StackNavigator.  Whenever the app navigates from one screen to another, it animates the navigation.  Is there a way to remove the animation or customize it?  StackNavigator also adds a title to each of my screen.  Is there a way to remove the screen title?  I tried setting the 'title' property of navigationOptions to an empty screen and the screen was rendered without a title.  However, navigating from this screen to another one will cause an exception.

e.g. the "welcome" title in these sample screens
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the header from a `stackNavigator` screen, set `headerMode` in `StackNavigatorConfig` to `none`. So, your `stackNavigator` should look like so:

```
import HomeScreen from 'path/to/screen';

const stack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  }
}, {
  headerMode: 'none' // <= here
});
```

There is an active proposal to allow the customization of animation in react navigation. You can follow this [open issue](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/175)